# MySQL: Use plus sign together with wildcard in fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, wildcard

I've tried the following query without any success; the initial wildcard for every word is for some reason ignored.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(field) AGAINST("+*foo* +*bar*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I've also tried to use brackets, but with no different result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(field) AGAINST("+(*foo*) +(*bar*)" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Shouldn't any of these work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql fulltext indexes support only searching for prefixes. So you can search for "foo*" but not "*foo*"

[More information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: Weird, because "*foo*" does actually work, but I can't make it obligatory.

Comment: Are you sure? By which I mean are words like 'stafooka' being included when you search for \*foo\* ?

Comment: I really appreciate your time :-) I can double-check the results when I get home. But if this really doesn't work, what would be the solution? Sphinx?

Comment: I just got what your initial comment meant. Yes it will search. But the wildcard be ignored. There is no workaround that I know of. You could look into [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)